# PHP variable not available after switch

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a result from a set of code into a variable, let's call it $Msg, however after the switch the variable doesn't seem to be set anymore. Sample code below:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    switch($_POST['formid']) {
        case "AOTEMP":
            //Other working code here removed
            $Msg = 'Succeeded';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'INVALID SUBMISSION RECEIVED';
            break;
    }
    if(!isset($Msg)) { $Msg = "Failed"; }
    if(!isset($error))
    {
        echo "<script>parent.self.location='http://SERVER/FILE.php?result=Success&Msg=".$Msg."';</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        //process errors here...
    }
```

Every time this returns Failed as the value of $Msg indicating that the previously set $Msg was no longer set when it reached the end of the switch.

I'm not sure what I'm missing but this seems like it should work. Any help would be appreciated.

Just to clarify I know the switch is working because there is other code inside the case that gets executed successfully.

Comment: If the variable is never set, it indicates that the case in switch is never met. Have you tried dumping `$_POST['formid']` to see what it contains?

Comment: try declare `$Msg = null;` above switch

Comment: @RonakDhoot that is not a declaration but an assignment. The variables are not declared in PHP. There isn't any way to declare them (apart from the `global` keyword but that's a different thing). And no matter how it is called, it does not help.

Comment: If the value of `$Msg` is always `'Failed'` I would look for the error message *"INVALID SUBMISSION RECEIVED"* into the output of the script. A `var_dump($_POST['formid'])` could also explain what `case` of the `switch` is executed.

Comment: There is not variable scope "per block" in PHP

Comment: I update the post but the other code in that case is working fine it’s just $Msg that for some reason doesn’t seem to stay set. I can echo $Msg inside the case and it prints, if I echo it after the case it apparently doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset IIS on one server and it began working on 1 of 32 servers in the load balanced pool, after an IIS reset on the others it’s started working there too. Case opened with Microsoft, their devops team is looking into it, left 2 servers broken for them to test, only time will tell.